# Trying to use MAX(): "Fatal error: Undefined class constant"

Tags: sql, mysql, criteria, propel

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addSelectColumn('MAX('.Moto::matricula.')');
```

But i get this error:

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant
>   'matricula' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/
>   prueba/lib/model/MotoPeer.php on line
>   25.

Any idea?

I'm using symfony 1.4 and propel 1.4.

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the class "Moto" doesn't have a variable "matricula" in it. This does not seem to have anything to do with (my)sql, but more with the (php?) class you are using.

Check out the source of that Moto class, and look if you have made a typo in the constant name?